# Assignment inside ternary operator doens't work in c

Tags: c++, c, conditional-operator

Why this doesn't work on C but works on C++?

```c
(0) ? a = 1 : a = 2;
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Best just to pretend noting you know from either works in the other.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's true, but there's enough overlap in the basic syntax that it's interesting that this is different.

Answer (score 7):

The languages have differences in operator precedence.

In [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the ternary operator has the same precedence as assignment operators, with the note

> The expression in the middle of the conditional operator (between `?` and `:`) is parsed as if parenthesized: its precedence relative to `?:` is ignored.

In [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the ternary operator has higher precedence than assignment. It also has a the same note about the middle expression.

What this means is that in C, the expression is parsed as if it were parenthesized:

```
((0) ? (a = 1) : a) = 2;
```

which is invalid because the conditional expression doesn't return an L-value.